# Show there are infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n$ divides $16^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$ such that $n\mid 16^n-1$.

Comment: I believe that tricks from here can be used to solve your specific problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842177/find-n-such-that-n-3n-1.

Comment: Try it for the powers of $5$

Comment: $16^n-1=(16-1)(polynomial)$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$

Comment: @Peter:  or powers of $3$

Comment: Cf. [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A014957)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by induction that $3^k|16^{3^k}-1$.

Base case:  $k=1:  3|16^3-1$.

Now assume $3^k|16^{3^k}-1$.

Note that $16^{3^{k+1}}-1=(16^{3^k}-1)(16^{2\cdot3^k}+16^{3^k}+1)$,

where the first factor is divisible by $3^k$ and the second factor is divisible by $3$,

so the product is divisible by $3^{k+1}$.

Comment: I believe a similar argument works for $5^k$, since $16^{5^{k+1}}-1=(16^{5^k}-1)(16^{4\cdot5^k}+16^{3\cdot5^k}+16^{2\cdot5^k}+16^{5^k}+1)$

Comment: More generally, I think we could show if $n|16^n-1$ then $3n|16^{3n}-1$

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring the idea of a modulus divisible by $5$ (because $\phi(5)=4$ which is the power of $2$ in the problem) when Peter commented with the right idea. So the credit belongs to that user. Indeed, since $$\phi(5^k)=5^k-5^{k-1}=4\cdot 5^{k-1},$$
Euler's congruence gives $$2^{4\cdot 5^{k-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{5^k}.$$
Then $$16^{5^{k-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{5^k}$$ and then you can just take the congruence to the power of $5.$

Comment: Similarly, $\phi(3^k)=2\cdot3^{k-1}, $ so $2^{2\cdot3^{k-1}}\equiv1\bmod 3^k$, so $4^{3^{k-1}}\equiv1\bmod 3^k$, and then take the $6$th power