# Show that infinitely many odd $n$ divide $2023^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Let $n$ be an odd natural number greater than $1.$ Find the two smallest $n$ such that $n$ is a factor of $2023^n-1.$ Show that infinitely many such $n$ exist.

The only progress I've made is finding the smallest solution: $3.$ I haven't found any other solution yet. I found $3$ relatively easily as $2023\equiv_31.$ I tried solving $2023\equiv_n1.$ This gives $2022=nk$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ This doesn't have infinite solutions, though. How to proceed?

PS: This was a question on an exam that ended $4$ hours ago.

Comment: Well, the same argument would work if, instead, of $2023$, you had, say, $2023^2$ and so on.

Comment: @lulu, what do you mean? $2023^5,$ for example, isn't congruent to $1$ modulo $5.$

Comment: No, I mean that your argument shows that $N^{N-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {N-1}$ for any $N$.  You used $N=2023$, but you could have used $N=2023^2$ and so on.

Comment: should have said, this is a way to construct infinitely many examples.  It clearly does not construct all of them (and I would not expect it to find the smallest ones).  In particular, there is another quite small $n$ that works...discoverable by trial and error.

Comment: @lulu, Well, suppose we take $N=2023^a.$ Such a $N$ is odd. Hence, the exponent, $2(N-1)$ is even. We want the exponent to be odd.

Comment: So, take $2023^3$.

Comment: @lulu, okay, we have $N=2023^3.$ Now, $N^{N-1}=(2023^3)^{(2023^3-1)}=2023^{3×2k},$ where $2k$ is some even number. Here, too, the exponent is even. I think I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: Maybe I got the parities wrong, I'll write it out carefully and post it if I can make it work.  In any case, there is an easier construction...which will become clear once you write down the next couple of odd examples.

Comment: Yeah, you're right...I can't make the parities work.  Since I generated confusion, let me say that the next two odd examples are $9$ and $27$.  There are, then, no odd examples until $81$.  That ought to make the pattern clear.  Though, of course, it requires proof.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for the pattern. I'll try to prove it.

Comment: First example outside that pattern is $171$, just to say.  But of course you don't need a full classification.

Comment: All $3^k$ numbers are answer to this question which are odd and infinite

Comment: @Anar $~2022 = 2 \times 3 \times 337.~$ So, $~n = 337^k~$ should also work.

Comment: @user2661923 Sure ,but $n=3^k$ is already enough to prove question.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747838/show-there-are-infinitely-many-natural-numbers-n-such-that-n-divides-16n-1?noredirect=1)

Comment: @AnneBauval, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euler theorem, when $n$ is coprime with $2023$ (which clearly happens for infinitely many odd $n$), $2023^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 [n]$. Therefore, we must look for $n$ such that $\varphi(n)|n$. In this case, $n = \varphi(n)k$ for an integer $k$ and $2023^n \equiv (2023^{\varphi(n)})^k \equiv 1 [n]$.

Look for $n =$ power of a prime number, their Euler's totient function are easy to compute.

Comment: So you're saying $2023^{\varphi(n)k}\equiv 1\pmod{\varphi(n)k}$? But this requires $(\varphi(n)k,2023)=1$.

Comment: If your notation $(a,b)$ means the gdc of $a$ and $b$, then yes, I said $n$ and $2023$ had to be coprime

Comment: You said $2023$ and $n$ are coprime but how did you get $\varphi(n)k$ and $2023$ are coprime? Actually you didnt specify $k$ so we can let $k=2023$ and then clearly  $\varphi(n)k$ and $2023$ aren't coprime.

Comment: I wrote $n = \varphi(n)k$ because I said that you need $n$ to be divisible by $\varphi(n)$. $k$ is simply $n/\varphi(n)$.